# the excel program will not closing from vba code in access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I need to empty an excel file that is linked to access database.

Because you can't delete data from within access a tried to write some VBA code that opens the excel file, delete the rows and then save and close excel.

Everything until closing excel was working, the workbook also closed but the excel program stayed open.

Now i changed so much that i have now even problems with saving the excel.

I completely lost it now :-(

Any help would be kind

```
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
xlApp.Visible = True


Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\\networklocation\bestellijst.xlsx", True, False)
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Bestelling 1")

LR = Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

' MsgBox LR

wb.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & LR).EntireRow.Delete

xlApp.Application.ScreenUpdating = True

wb.Save
wb.Close

x1App.Quit
Set x1App = Nothing
```

I search on different website for different solutions but nothing worked

I just want to open the excel file, delete some rows, save the file and close excel completely

Last thing i did today is put the code for closing like this:

`Excel.Application.Quit`

But then there is a background excel instance still active and the next time a run the vba i get an fault on the "range" code.

If i manually end process of the excel everything is fine again, i go crazy

Comment: Let me guess: You don't use `Option Explicit` and therefore never saw that `xlApp` and `x1App` are not the same...

Comment: _Tools ~ Options ~ Editor Tab ~ Require Variable Declaration_ will add `Option Explicit` to the top of any new modules you create.  Existing ones you'll have to type it in manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub test()

    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    With xlApp
        .Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        .Visible = True
    End With
    
    Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX.xlsx")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    With ws
        'Get last row of column A
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Delete lines
        .Rows("2:" & LastRow).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    
    'Save & close workbook
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
    'Close application
    xlApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Error 1004 thanks this is it everything is closing. but now i can't delete the rows anymore with the code i wrote, with yours rows 4:7 it works but i want the rows starting from row 2 to the last row being deleted in same action, my way with range doesn't work anymore, any ideas ???

Comment: find the last row before the delete line and change the delete line to `ws.Rows("2:" & LastRow).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: this doesn't work i changed "ws.Rows("4:7").EntireRow.Delete" to "ws.Rows("2:" & LastRow).EntireRow.Delete" and i get error message 13 types doesn't match?? do i need to change something else??

Comment: please share your code

Comment: `Private Sub Knop19_Click()

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

With xlApp
    .Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    .Visible = True
End With

Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\\Magazijn\acces Stockbeheer\Bestellijst\bestellijst.xlsx", True, False)
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Bestelling 1")
 
ws.Rows("2:" & LastRow).EntireRow.Delete

wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

xlApp.Quit


End Sub` Thanks for the help

Comment: @Tommy as i mention in my previous comment, you should declare LastRow variable `Dim LastRow As Long` and calculate LastRow before you use it. Please see edited answer.